Unable to boot from USB on raspberry pi 5
I have a raspberry pi 5, and it won't boot from any image on any usb drive, but it works fine on microSD. I already tried setting nvme/usb to priority (to no avail) and tried flashing a drive with the boot tool specifically designed to switch it to boot from usb. The green LED status flashes green twice (which isn't found anywhere in the manual) and then goes solid green. After around a minute it will repeat the pattern. Every time the pattern repeats, the status lights on the usb drives also indicate that they are being used. I can't see any outputs since the only display I have requires ssh in order to download the drivers for it.

This is the weird LED pattern that I have not been able to find any documentation for.
I tried adding
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install rpi-update 

sudo BRANCH=next rpi-update

echo program_usb_boot_mode=1 | sudo tee -a /boot/config.txt

to config.txt but it didn't change anything.
When using raspi-config, this is the message it gave me when I switched the boot order to prioritize usb devices

EDIT: adding on to the things I've tried, I tried using the eeprom manager found here, but it just reboots, does the 2 flashes thing, and then boots back up from the sd card.
FINAL EDIT: updated bootloader using eeprom manager to a slightly older one, changed boot order, and it worked.


what is the USB device you are trying to boot from? can you explain what you meant by flashing a drive with the boot tool ... is that on a microSD or some USB device (it's clear your Pi can't boot from USB, so no matter what you put on the USB it won't boot from it) - also, those lines in config.txt will not help, since config.txt is NOT a scripting file, it's a configuration text file - and also since your Pi doesn't boot from USB ... well, you can see the issue, right

I'm using the raspberry pi imager, I tried both lite and full 64 bit raspbian.

what is the USB device you are trying to boot from?

@JaromandaX it is a transcend MLC 16gb usb drive. I also tried a Sandisk Cruzer 8gb drive, and for overkill, a WD 232gb external hard drive

so, USB thumb drives and an SSD?

usb thumb drives, yes, but the MLC one is faster than most microSD cards. and it was a spinning disk hard drive.

forget the spinning rust drive - I don't think you can power those through a Pi (I could be wrong with the Pi 5, but spinning rust does NOT work on a Pi 4)

either way, doesn't explain why both thumb drives failed. one is 3d nand vlc, one is mlc. they both should run fine.

true - I guess you've tried all the USB ports (even the USB2 ones)?

I tried all the usb ports, and it still didn't work

microsd works though - and if you have a USB->SD adapter, does it work with the microsd that works?

I do not have an adapter like that. I have one that converts microsd to usb, but that doesn't work

well, clearly I meant microSD because I assume you used that adapter to "flash" the microsd - sorry, I don't have a Pi5 so I'm not 100% sure if it should boot from USB "out of the box" - perhaps it needs a firmware update (like the Pi 4's did when they were first released) - when you boot from microsd, what is the CURRENT bootloader version if you run rpi-eeprom-update

the bootloader is up to date, but the raspberry pi 5 supported usb boot from release

"I tried adding...to config.txt" -> Is that a typo?  That's not a shell script and this may be causing additional problems  and/or preventing whatever real solution from working.  It isn't interpreted by a shell, and it's not executed by the OS.  It's used by the bootloader firmware before the OS is loaded. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html

@goldilocks it was a solution I saw online that I removed. Still isn't working. I tried putting the usb boot tool on the sd card and then plugging in both sd card and a usb, and it started rapidly flashing the green light at a rate of around 2 flashes per second

@JaromandaX It will boot from USB by default if you don't have an SD card in (presuming there's a properly formatted USB drive). @Swerve: Wherever you saw that "solution", if it really said put that in config.txt, never read anything from there again.

Is dtparam=pciex1 in config.txt file to boot the NVMe drive??
